# Join table on null where condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have tables `Member` and `Transaction`. Table `Member` has 2 columns `MemberID` and `MemberName`. Table `Transaction` has 3 columns, `MemberID`, `TransactionDate`, and `MemberBalance`.

The rows in the tables are as shown below:

Table `Member`:

```
MemberID           MemberName
=============================
1                  John
2                  Betty
3                  Lisa
```

Table `Transaction`:

```
MemberID        TransactionDate         MemberBalance
=====================================================
1               13-12-2012              200
2               12-12-2012              90
1               10-09-2012              300
```

I would like to query for `MemberID, MemberName` and `MemberBalance` where the `TransactionDate` is the latest (max) for each `MemberID`.

My query is like this:

```
SELECT 
    t.MemberID, m.MemberName , t.MemberBalance
FROM 
    Member AS m 
INNER JOIN 
    Transaction AS t ON m.MemberID = t.MemberID 
WHERE 
    t.TransactionDate IN (SELECT MAX(TransactionDate)
                          FROM Transaction 
                          GROUP BY MemberID)
```

This query returns:

```
MemberID           MemberName         MemberBalance
===================================================
1                  John               200
2                  Betty              90
```

My problem is, I want the query to return:

```
MemberID           MemberName         MemberBalance
===================================================
1                  John               200
2                  Betty              90
3                  Lisa               NULL
```

I want the member to be displayed even if its `MemberID` does not exist in the `Transaction` table.

How do I do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `LEFT JOIN`. Also you had an error in your query because if two members had transactions at the same time you can get two rows for both the users.

Try this

```
SELECT t.MemberID, m.MemberName , t.MemberBalance
FROM Member AS m 
    LEFT JOIN Transaction AS t ON m.MemberID = t.MemberID AND t.TransactionDate=
    ( 
        SELECT MAX(TransactionDate)
        FROM Transaction T2
        WHERE T2.MemberID=t.MemberID
    )
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have tried it but it is not working. I get this error: "An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ')'."

Comment: @ixora I don't have 2005 at hand to test it but on 2008 it is OK.

Comment: This is embarrassing but I must have made a mistake when I tried the query for the first time. It is working and thank you for your help. Sorry for the inconvenience caused.

Comment: @ixora You are welcome. Don't be embarrassed, sometimes it happens :)

Answer (score 5):

You can also use something like this:

```
SELECT m.MemberID, m.MemberName, t1.MemberBalance
FROM Member AS m 
LEFT JOIN
(
  select max(transactionDate) transactionDate, 
    MemberID
  from Transactions
  group by MemberID
) AS t 
  ON m.MemberID = t.MemberID 
left join transactions t1
  on t.transactionDate = t1.transactionDate
  and t.memberid = t1.memberid
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d4820/11)

Answer (score 2):

> member to be displayed even if its MemberID does not exist in Transaction table

You can preserve rows using LEFT JOIN on the Member table to Transaction table.

> where the TransactionDate is the latest (max) for each MemberID.

From SQL Server 2005 onwards, the preferred and better performing method is to use [ROW_NUMBER()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

```
   SELECT MemberID, MemberName, MemberBalance
     FROM (
   SELECT m.MemberID, m.MemberName , t.MemberBalance,
          row_number() over (partition by m.MemberID order by t.TransactionDate desc) rn
     FROM Member AS m 
LEFT JOIN [Transaction] AS t ON m.MemberID = t.MemberID 
        ) X
    WHERE rn=1;
```

Comment: This works too. ROW_NUMBER() method is new to me so I'll read more on this. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

To keep member in the result set, you need an outer join.

Also, please don't forget to add a condition on memberid for inner select query, as you might get issues when a maximum date for one user would match a non-maximum date of another (your where condition would pass twice for the second user as his transaction dates would appear on the select's results twice, one would be his actual maximum date and another - the max date of some user matching a non-max date)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.MemberId,a.MemberName,a.MemberBalance
FROM
(
SELECT m.MemberId,m.MemberName,t1.MemberBalance
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY m.MemberId ORDER BY t1.TransactionDate DESC) AS RN
FROM
@Member m OUTER APPLY (SELECT t.MemberId,t.MemberBalance,t.TransactionDate
                       FROM @Transaction t WHERE m.MemberId=t.MemberId) t1
)a
WHERE a.RN=1
```